# Can I manage content of my custom site using wordpress?

Tags: cms

I might be asking a really dumb question but I want to know for sure whether or not I can link wordpress to my own site(own domain with own interface - not theme) and edit content in it.

My site is already implemented and there is a sector called 'Articles' to which I want to keep adding posts in the future. I want them to use my own interface design and I want only the content to change when I add a new post. The new entry must also come as a new element under 'Articles' dropdown list. I'm sure this is possible with wordpress but I just want to make sure.

Or will using my own CMS be easier than incorporating WP?

Comment: Did any of our answers help? If so then please consider marking one as accepted to help keep the site tidy.  If not, then by all means add your own answer explaining what worked for you and accept that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Rest API to feed content into your site or otherwise interact with WordPress for storing content. http://v2.wp-api.org eventually all this will move into WP Core so V2 is a good place to start.

Then set WP_USE_THEMES to false in your wp-config.php. That will allow you to use WP as your CMS but not load the theme visuals.

From there it's just a lot of JavaScript calls so something like jQuery or Angular would help.

Answer (score 1):

Is WordPress *meant* for such use? Nope, not really.

Is it *possible* ? Yes, and in quite a few ways. It's actually hard to recommend any specific one.

On top of my head the following approaches are common and suit different requirements (primarily how far apart stuff is from each other):

- do a custom load of installed WP core and use its APIs to retrieve data;
- retrieve data from WP’s database table;
- retrieve WP’s RSS feed;
- retrieve data over REST API (upcoming native or custom one).

Comment: Then using my own cms will be easier than incorporating WP?

Comment: I don't think writing whole CMS is ever "easier" than using existing one, though there are other reasons to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Good answers here already, but if what you want is for /articles/ to run using WordPress then a simple approach is to make a theme from your current site's HTML and CSS and install WordPress in the directory /articles/

There are drawbacks such as making sure that your headers, particularly site wide navigation, and footers stay up-to-date whenever you change those, but this is a quick way of getting WP blog functionality into an existing site.

Answer (score -1):

```
write below line in your wp-config.php
WP_USE_THEMES = false;
then include wp-load.php in your custom article page
include_once('../wp-config.php');
//give relative file path of your wordpress files path above
then you can use wordpress functions to get post data
```

https://codex.wordpress.org